# VSCode Kernel Selector when clicked does not display any options

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, kernel

Despite having multiple interpreters available (3.10.8, 3.9.13 from anaconda), whenever I click "Select Kernel" in my ipynb notebook, nothing comes up except for "Install suggested extensions Python + Jupyter," none of which are helpful since I already have the suggested extensions installed. Does anyone know how I can appropriately select a kernel here?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I uninstalled, then reinstalled VSCode. base (Python 3.9.13) was instantly selected for me upon opening the reinstalled version of VSC.